# How can I make my dialog box cover the whole screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm following this angular light box tutorial [here](http://adamalbrecht.com/2013/12/12/creating-a-simple-modal-dialog-directive-in-angular-js/).  When I put the button inside a div the light box only expands to the size of the div.  My code looks something like:

```
<div class='newPen'>
  <div ng-app='mean.items' ng-controller='MyCtrl'>
    <button ng-click='toggleModal()'>Open Modal Dialog</button>
    <modal-dialog show='modalShown' width='1000px' height='1000px'>
      <p>Modal Content Goes here<p>
    </modal-dialog>
  </div>
</div>
```

But the lightbox only shows in the div.  How can I make my lightbox show up for the whole page?

If you need anymore information let me know.

Edit:

Here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/aDuJIku/100/) that I've made.  In the example the model box gets messed up because of position absolute.  The problem is in my code I have a bunch of css position absolutes... So is there anyway I can make the modal box cover the whole screen while maintaining my parent div's position absolute?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Try setting your modal size in the script itself ...

Comment: I can't recreate your problem, maybe include your CSS or supply a fiddle that recreates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css

```
.ng-modal-dialog {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

Hope this helps...............